# getting error in browsing files in windows using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have collected a code in c# for browsing files and folders in windows. My sample code  segment is as follows:

```
void ButtonbrowseOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    int size = -1;
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
        string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        try
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
            size = text.Length;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(size); // <-- Shows file size in debugging mode.
    Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
}
```

But, I am getting the following error:

```
The name 'openFileDialog1' does not exist in the current context
```

What's wrong in the code segment?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have defined the `openFileDialog1`? Changing the second line of your method to the bellow, seems to solve the problem

```
void ButtonbrowseOnClick(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    int size = -1;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();  //define the variable
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();  

    //your code
```

Comment: solved the error but getting the follwing exception 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadStateException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll @Hossein Narimani Rad

Comment: Can your provide more information about your project type? Is it a windows forms app?

Comment: no. can you please provode me a full demo code for browsing a file from windows? @Hossein Narimani Rad

Comment: @ACE check your `static void Main` method and see if you have `[STAThread]` attribute on top of you `Main` method

Comment: can you please help me with the following question? @Hossein Narimani Rad 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797552/click-button-not-working-in-server-gui-program

Comment: @Hossein Narimani Rad this is the question link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797552/click-button-not-working-in-server-gui-program

Answer (score 3):

It does not exist cause it hasn't been defined.

`OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();`